Testing Value Objects in DDD, "Implementing Domain Driven Design"
In the book "Implementing Domain Driven Design" of Vaughn Vernon, in the Testing of Value Objects section, the author talks about how we can use just shallow copy instead of  deep copy to test the mutability of an object.
This is the constructor of BusinessPriority
public final class BusinessPriority implements Serializable {
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
 private BusinessPriorityRatings ratings;
 public BusinessPriority(BusinessPriorityRatings aRatings) {
     super();
     this.setRatings(aRatings);
 }
 public BusinessPriority(BusinessPriority aBusinessPriority) {
     this(aBusinessPriority.ratings());
 }

This is the testcase
 public void testCostPercentageCalculation() throws Exception {
     BusinessPriority businessPriority = new BusinessPriority(
         new BusinessPriorityRatings(2, 4, 1, 1));
     BusinessPriority businessPriorityCopy =
         new BusinessPriority(businessPriority);
 
    assertEquals(businessPriority, businessPriorityCopy);
 
    BusinessPriorityTotals totals = new BusinessPriorityTotals(53, 49, 53 + 49, 37, 33);
 
    float cost = businessPriority.costPercentage(totals);
    
    assertEquals(this.oneDecimal().format(cost), "2.7");
    assertEquals(businessPriority, businessPriorityCopy);
 }

This is the equals method
@Override
 public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    boolean equalObjects = false;
    if (anObject != null && this.getClass() == anObject.getClass()) {
        BusinessPriority typedObject = (BusinessPriority) anObject;
        equalObjects =
        this.ratings().equals(typedObject.ratings());
    }
    return equalObjects;
 }


As I can see, shallow copying is not enough in this case, because shallow copying will make businessPriority.rating() and businessPriorityCopy.rating() refer to the same object, thus always equal regardless of whether some attribute of this object is changed or not
So am I correct and if so, why the book talks about shallow copying in this case ?
/////////////////////

"why the book talks about shallow copying in this case" because reviewers didn't catch the error before it went to print?

Because he is not testing the equality on ratings but instead of the value object holding the rating.
because they are equal by value (and not reference), think a value object as a java 17 records, the test demonstrates that two immutable objects remains equals by shallow copy.

Hi Sylvain, your comment does give me some insight about the picture here.
Yet I still have some questions.
Firstly, if I understand you correctly, the last assertion will take a part of ensuring the immutability of the Value Object businessPriority (together with the first assertion). But in case the value of an attribute of businessPriority change - violating the immutability, how can the test detect it ?
Can you give me  an example to see why the last assertion is  necessary?

Hi Khoa, actually the businessPriority is also immutable, this is a good practice, so an attribute of businessPriority cannot change at all.
Look at the class in full extent: https://github.com/VaughnVernon/IDDD_Samples/blob/master/iddd_agilepm/src/main/java/com/saasovation/agilepm/domain/model/product/backlogitem/BusinessPriority.java
The setter is private
